# Porting an MFC lib to linux and ASSERT

Tags: c++, gcc, mfc, assert

I have an average c++ background however i haven't developed anything with MFC, and i came across a Lib which i need to make portable and there are alot of calls for assert for example

```
void putValue(LPCTSTR lpszValue)
    {
        ASSERT(AfxIsValidString(lpszValue));
                .
                .
                .
        }
```

and in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa297139%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

> The most typical use of the ASSERT macro is to identify program
>   errors during development. The argument  given to ASSERT should be
>   chosen so that it holds true only if the program is operating as
>   intended. The  macro evaluates the ASSERT argument and, if the
>   argument expression is false (0), alerts the user and halts  program
>   execution. No action is taken if the argument is true (nonzero).

if i were to port this to be compiled in GCC, is the right thing to do is putting the condition in an if statement and throw an exception id the condition was valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can simply:

```
#ifndef ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#define ASSERT assert
#endif
```